# Selecting a row based on another column's condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following output:

```
ApplicationNumber ApplicationStatusCode CreatedOn      AppStat_Disbursed/Unc

1                 AnnuledCL             1.3.2019 8:44  Uncompleted
2                 AnnuledCL             1.3.2019 8:45  Uncompleted
3                 Paid                  1.3.2019 8:54  Disbursement
3                 Paid                  1.3.2019 8:54  Uncompleted
4                 Paid                  1.3.2019 8:59  Disbursement
4                 Paid                  1.3.2019 8:59  Uncompleted
4                 Paid                  1.3.2019 8:59  Uncompleted
5                 Paid                  1.3.2019 9:03  Uncompleted
6                 RejectedAS            1.3.2019 9:04  Uncompleted
```

What I am trying to achieve is to remove duplicate application_numbers with the following condition. If there is more than one entry for an ApplicationNumber (i.e. duplicate entries) it should select and prioritise rows that have "Disbursement" status over "Uncompleted". However, if there is no "Disbursement" Status for that applicationNumber it should take any row from the "Uncompleted" status.

That is the desired outcome:

```
ApplicationNumber ApplicationStatusCode CreatedOn     AppStat_Disbursed/Unc
1                 AnnuledCL             1.3.2019 8:44  Uncompleted
2                 AnnuledCL             1.3.2019 8:45  Uncompleted
3                 Paid                  1.3.2019 8:54  Disbursement
4                 Paid                  1.3.2019 8:59  Disbursement
5                 Paid                  1.3.2019 9:03  Uncompleted
6                 RejectedAS            1.3.2019 9:04  Uncompleted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this would be adding a `ROW_NUMBER` partitioned by the `ApplicationNumber` and then additionally ordered by the `AppStat_Disbursed/Unc`

```
SELECT ApplicationNumber
      ,ApplicationStatusCode
      ,CreatedOn
      ,[AppStat_Disbursed/Unc]
  FROM (
            SELECT *
                  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ApplicationNumber 
                                          ORDER BY ApplicationNumber, [AppStat_Disbursed/Unc])
                             AS rn
              FROM YOURTABLE
       ) A
 WHERE rn = 1
```